# How to remove audio focus in React Native WebView?

Tags: react-native, webview

I checked on the [library](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview), but it doesn't seem to have an option for removing the audio focus. Is there any workaround/technique to do so?

I'm trying to play music in a Webview without interrupting a background app sound.

Comment: basically what i guess is youre trying to do audio ducking, where if suppose spotify is already playing songs, and if your audio is triggered it shouldnt play right?

Comment: Hi, @GauravRoy, sorry what I want is to keep playing the Spotify song even though I trigger the play audio